# Static SPA website in AWS S3 but do i need WAF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

Reading through AWS documentation  and found this implementation.
My site will be developed in client side frameworks like React or Angular etc..

I am not sure this design is OK if:

1. Number of users per second on my site is 0.5 million or more
2. Do i need WAF to be configured as well? Except from User Registration , Login page other pages does NOT have any data entry fields..

[image]